# Is it possible to use MathML to describe data tables?

Tags: java, frameworks, mathml

I'm using `JEuclid` library for rendering `MathML` script. I want to display data tables using `MathML`.

I googled it but all the results describe `mtable` with examples showing describing matrices.

So, I'm puzzled whether it is possible. In our current framework, it's not possible to use any other resources except graphics object of `JPanel` or `MathML` script.

So, please point me in the right direction. Any links to examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean - data tables - just grids of numbers?

Comment: @Randy like statistics tables....like html tables (no hifi formatting needed)

Comment: I doubt if this question really fits in stackoverflow, is there any stackexchange site to which this question fits more perfectly...?

Comment: My impression from a quick glance through the MathML spec is that the only `table` construction (in presentation MathML, at least) is `mtable`, so I suspect that what you want to acheive would better be done using the HTML `<table>` element.  Something like `<table><tr><td><math><mn>3.2</mn></math></td><td><math><mn>0</mn></math></td></tr><tr><td><math><mn>.234</mn></math></td><td><math><mn>5.12</mn></math></td></tr></table>`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch but can JEuclid render that html script?

Comment: @pinkpanther I don't know, and haven't got time to install JEuclid.  Have you tried with the HTML `<table>` element?  Have you tried with `<mtable>`, and if so, what is the output, and what is wrong with it?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch there is no table element in mathml. Possibly mtable is the way for both matrices and tables, that's what i'm trying to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mtable` is not specifically for matrices (in particular it does not add parenthesis around the data) It is used for all vertical alignment layouts such as tables and aligned equations.

Comment: thanks, I would be delighted if you could give me an example sort of thing or at least the links to the page, where is such an example is made :)

Comment: @pinkpanther not sure what example you want, you just surround each number with `<mtd><mn>` surround each row with `<mtr>` and surround the whole table with `<mtable>`

Comment: I mean the example which shows how to write script which seem like a table, with cols and rows in between borders.... is it possible? does it give flexibility as such?

Comment: @pinkpanther http://www.w3.org/Math/testsuite/build/main/Presentation/TablesAndMatrices/mtable/mtableAlines2-simple.xhtml

Comment: thank you very much... :) these things don't come up in google much... and not cared in SO either.... I posted in `tex.stackexchange.com` and was offtopic there.. finally you have solved my problem.... :) thanks ....